# How can I schedule cleanup of abandoned files on a Persistent Volume mounted into a StatefulSet pod?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a `StatefulSet` which has a Persistent Volume (AWS EBS). I have a single container in my pod which is a HTTP service that ingests files, processes them, and then deletes them synchronously. I use a persistent volume because the files are often much larger than I can store in an `emptyDir`, and a subset of the files must persist after a pod is terminated.

Occasionally an error is encountered and a file which is uploaded is not successfully deleted. In order to ensure the EBS volume does not fill up over time as errors accumulate, I need to periodically delete files with modified times older than a few hours.

My initial thought was to run a separate process inside my container which periodically cleans up the volume. Either a shell script that runs on a loop, or a crontab script. But it seems like an anti-pattern to have a second, background process running in a container.

I considered using a `CronJob` resource in Kubernetes to periodically clean up the volumes, but it seems to be challenging to ensure a `CronJob` has access to the same volumes my `StatefulSet` pods. And with the volumes being `ReadWriteOnce` it seems I would have to ensure the `CronJob` pods are scheduled on the same node as the `StatefulSet` pod for each volume, which seems challenging.

Is there a simpler option I can use to perform maintenance on these persistent volumes that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Just update your StatefulSets to include a `cron` container that runs the periodic cleanup tasks? Since it's part of the same pod you don't need to worry about RWO vs RWX volumes.

Comment: Thank you @larsks that's a good idea. I have very little experience with Kubernetes and am learning as I go, so I appreciate this suggestion even though it is probably obvious to those with more experience. I used this approach and it resolved my issue, so I would mark your comment as the answer if I could.

Comment: @larsks, can you provide your comment as an answer for the greater visibility of the community